# How can I diff 2 collections and produce an updated struct for updating a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array of data, modelled using `Structs` and conforming as  `Codable` and `Equatable`

```
enum FeedItemType: String, Codable {
    case selling = "ITEM_FOR_SALE"
    case facebook = "FACEBOOK_POST"
    case tweet = "TWITTER_POST"
}

enum FeedItemStatus: String, Codable {
    case created = "CREATED"
}

struct FeedItem: Codable, Equatable {
    var item: FeedItemContent
    var liked: Bool
    var commented: Bool

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case liked, commented
        case item = "feedItem"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.item = try container.decode(FeedItemContent.self, forKey: .item)
        self.liked = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .liked)
        self.commented = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .commented)
    }
}
```

I iterate over an array of this and populate a `UITableView` with the contents of `FeedItemContent` which itself is also `Codable` and `Equatable`.

As this list of data is paginated and can be updated server side, when fetching new data, rather than reload the entire `UITableView` I'd like to only make changes to rows that are different or append new rows that are missing from the original collection.

Coming from a JS background I would normally just spread the old object and the new object over a new empty object and let React figure out what has changed.

I am unsure how to achieve this in Swift / iOS.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does the order of the data that comes server-side change? Or are new items inserted between old items (you have `[a, b, c]` now it becomes `[a, b, x, y, c]`)?

Comment: The order does not change, but perhaps a property on that item has changed. So if I liked a post on my app and then unliked it on the web for example

Comment: Wait, is the list always the same, but the properties on the items the ones that change?

Comment: It could be the same or new items could be added or removed. The list itself is a feed of posts, they could be deleted or updated server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst your question is a little hard to follow, it sounds like you are trying to update only the relevant rows in a tableview when fetching new data.

There are a number of ways to achieve this using various diffing algorithms, however I myself generally use [Dwifft](https://github.com/jflinter/Dwifft) as it purpose built for this thing, very fast and extremely lightweight.

> Dwifft is a small Swift library that tells you what the "diff" is
>   between two collections, namely, the series of "edit operations"
>   required to turn one into the other. It also comes with UIKit
>   bindings, to automatically, animatedly keep a
>   UITableView/UICollectionView in sync with a piece of data by making
>   the necessary row/section insertion/deletion calls for you as the data
>   changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update only relevant rows in tableview at the time of fetching new data then use Dwifft as it will serve your purpose very well.